# Subdiving Alembic Crashes Blender

Tags: mesh, import, alembic

So importing an alembic from Houdini and wanted to throw a subdivide modifier on it and every time it crashes blender. Can confirm the alembic can be subdivided in C4D
Here's a link to the file. Just make sure the alembic is targeting the right directory

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ljsmdq7wp1mov2/Alembic%20Test.zip?dl=0

Comp specs are fine, also just using a light file for troubleshooting before anything heavy comes into blender ie. fluidsim
2x 2080ti
128gb ram
AMD 2950x 16 core 3.5ghz

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need more information about the object, it is possible the object has become to complex  for your machine with additional modifiers added to it. Please [edit] your question and add images at least.

Comment: Usually Blender wil lock-up when crunching alot of information, as long as nothing is pressed during this time you usually get through it after 10-40 seconds, if anything gets pressed it locks permanently and it usually needs to be manually shutdown.

Comment: I think it could be in a constant loop as this alembic I was using had nothing to subdiv on the first few frames be fore the type scales up and out. Feel free to test it out with the file in the dropbox link. 

As for subdiving other alembics with success, yes blender does take a while to figure out what it needs to do. Guess its not optimized as much as what C4D as it instantly subdiv'd it